# Am I understanding how a Confidence Interval is obtained?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

**In short:** I'm wondering if I'm understanding the concept of two-sided *"Confidence Interval"* via an example?

## Details:

Suppose we observe **5** successes in **20** trials and so our observed $p = 5/20$. To obtain a 95% CI for the PARAMETER of this observed $p$, we argue this way:

What the unknown, fixed PARAMETER value of this observed $p$ could be such that out of infinitely many repetitions of a binomial experiment with $20$ trials, $95\%$ of the time we capture that PARAMETER value? Now we take two steps:

First, we find the $p$ of a binomial distribution given **20** trials which strictly allows **2.5%** probability for **5 or more successes** in **20** trials to happen in large repetitions (the *blue binomial distribution*). This $p$ can be shown (e.g., by optimization or via Clopper & Pearson) to be "$0.08657147$". This will be the smallest limit value if we were to construct a 95%-coverage uncertainty net to capture the PARAMETER value of the observed $p$. In other words, this "$0.08657147$" is the smallest possible $p$ for a binomial distribution given 20 trials that allows at least **2.5%** probability for 5 success out of 20 trials to occur in large repetitions.

Second, we find the $p$ of a binomial distribution given **20** trials which strictly allows **2.5%** probability for **5 or less successes** in **20** trials to happen in large repetitions (the *red dashed binomial distribution*). This $p$ can be shown (by optimization or via Clopper & Pearson) to be "$0.49104587$". This will be the largest limit value if we were to construct a 95%-coverage uncertainty net to capture the PARAMETER value of the observed $p$. In other words, this "$0.49104587$" is the largest possible $p$ for a binomial distribution given **20** trials that allows at most **2.5%** probability for **5** success out of 20 trials to occur in large repetitions.

[image]

Comment: The interval will differ if you have a one-sided versus a two-sided interval.

Comment: I agree with your second paragraph.  The interval you show is described correctly for a two-sided equal tailed interval.  The figures you show are confusing.  I don't see why you produce two beta curves and also don't understand what the two binomial distributions are for.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, that's the [Clopper & Pearson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), that is what the $Beta$ distributions are for.

Comment: I think there is only one distribution for which you determine upper and lower tails.  Yes the Clopper-Pearson method is one way to calculate exact binomial probabilities.  Also two tailed 95% confidence intervals do not need to be equal tailed.  The definition allows say 1% in the lower tail and 4% in the upper (for example) rather than 2.5% in each tail.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I assume by "there is only one distribution for which you determine upper and lower tails", you 're referring to "Normal Approximation" which due to the symmetry of a normal distribution doesn't require two distribution. But I did not ask about that approximation. Furthermore, generally speaking, one-distribution method has limited generality as many important statistics follow asymmetrical distributions for which an approximation is not known. One thing I do want to know, though, how a $Binomial$ distribution can directly be converted back to a corresponding $Beta$ ...

Comment: ... distribution given the structure of the two distributions?

Comment: I think there is a conceptual problem here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, see pages 6 and 7 of [**THIS BOOK**](https://books.google.com/books?id=1ZEMXC-Xc9gC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: I think I am thinking of the pivotal quanttity having one distribution.  I suppose that when you hypothesize different values for the true parameters you can view it as looking at two distributions.  You are correct in your approach.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, Michael I always thought like you did, that is an observed estimate of a parameter has one distribution and so all we need to do is to construct a $x\%$ CI "around" our estimate using this one distribution. Of course in the context of normal distributions this, as an exception, works. BUT, the concept of CI can be easily misunderstood in more complex cases. Even to say we construct a CI "around" our estimate is kind of misleading as the two-distribution method shows we are basically looking for a uncertainty capture net to get the fixed Parameter itself.

Answer (score 1):

This image may help your understanding:

[image: Two-sided vs one-sided intervals]

Essentially for a two-sided confidence interval, it ranges from an upper to a lower limit, with 2.5% chance on both sides.

A one-sided confidence interval exists when you only look at values above OR below a certain null value (the value that satisfies the null hypothesis). The 95% CI, and the 5% outside the interval, are both above or both below the null value.

Comment: You can think of a one-sided intervals as going off to plus or minus infinity (or perhaps some finite bound that makes sense, like 100 for conversion rates). The overlap between two one-sided (1-a)% CIs makes one two-sided 2a% CI where each one-sided interval contributes one bound.